# Object does not support this property or method error

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to copy data from excel to fallible PDF form. with below code, I open fallible form  and populate the data and I need to save using varibale 'pr' .
While saving it is throwing run time error

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
Dim fcount As Long
Dim sFieldName As String

Set AcrobatApplication = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AcrobatDocument = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If AcrobatDocument.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\Jan 2018\Excel to PDF\Test.pdf", "") Then
    AcrobatApplication.Show
    Set AcroForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App")
    Set Fields = AcroForm.Fields
    fcount = Fields.Count    ' Number of Fields

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Fields("Enter county name").Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            Fields("Enter county served").Value = Range("B" & i).Value
            Fields("Parcel number").Value = Range("C" & i).Value
            pr = Range("C" & i).Value
            Fields("Property owner name").Value = Range("D" & i).Value

            fname = "C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\Jan 2018\Excel to PDF\docs\" & pr & ".pdf"

            If AcrobatDocument.Save(PDSaveFull, fname) = False Then
                MsgBox ("Cannot save the modified document")

            End If

        Next
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "failure"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dim  pr as String`

should be enough considering the fact that you are using it only here:

```
fname = "C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\Jan 2018\Excel to PDF\docs\" & pr & ".pdf"
```